# Как проверять посимвольно поле ввода?

Tags: python, tkinter, ввод, символы

Задача в следующем: дана строка ---> c.create_text(100, 100, text='Текст'), нужно вводить в поле ввода эту строку по-символьно,т.е. мы вводим c после чего нам выдаёт текст ---> продолжайте ввод, а если ввели иной  символ выдаёт текст ---> неверный символ, и так остальные символы. Я пытался через обычные условия if else, в котором ещё следующее условие, и в котором ещё одно условие, но такой вариант очень громоздкий и непонятный, как можно реализовать правильнее?

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x400')

c = Canvas(root)

c.create_text(100, 100, text='Текст')
c.pack()

field = Entry()
field.pack()
def correct():
    a = field.get()
    if a == 'c':
        print("Вводите дальше")
    else:
        print("Можно вводить только символы ")

butt = Button(root, text ="Проверить", command = lambda:correct())
butt.place(x=150, y=200)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В tkinter есть встроенная валидация. Я считаю, логичнее всего применять здесь именно её.

[Ссылка на валидацию в оф. документации](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/entry.htm#M16)

```
 from tkinter import *


def char_validate(d, P):
    pattern = "c.create_text(100, 100, text='Текст')"
    if d == '1':
        if P == pattern:
            print('Вы правильно ввели всю строку')
        elif pattern.startswith(P):
            print('Вводите дальше')
        else:
            print('Введен неверный символ!')
    return True


root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x400')

field_check = (root.register(char_validate),"%d", "%P")
c = Canvas(root)

c.create_text(100, 100, text='Текст')
c.pack()

field = Entry(validate="key", validatecommand=field_check)
field.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Спасибо, но есть вопрос после того, как я записал всю строку как я могу добавить оповещение об этом или чтобы запрещалось вводить?

Comment: и ещё вопрос один вопрос: когда ввел несколько неверных символов и стёр их, то не получается ввести верные, тогда всегда выводить: введен неверный символ

Comment: Я обновил код, теперь при стирании неверных символов все корректно работает, а когда вся строка введена, выводится сообщение об этом

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

можно так:

```
def correct(var):
    content = var.get()

    if re.findall(r"[^a-zA-Z]", content) == []:
        print("Вводите дальше")
    else:
        print("Можно вводить только символы ")


var = StringVar()
var.trace("w", lambda name, index,mode, var=var: correct(var))

field = Entry(textvariable=var)
field.pack()
```

Comment: Почему выдаёт ошибку ---> name 're' is not defined

Comment: `import re` делали?

Comment: так в вашем коде регулярка не соответствует фразе "c.create_text(100, 100, text='Текст')" или это пример?

Comment: пример - регулярка просто для проверки что вводятся только символы